# Adding generated column existing table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to add a generated column in existing table. I've a transaction table, in that table I've one column named as dateTime(containing date and time in timestamp format). I want  to create a virtual column named as transactionDate which will contain a date and time derived from dateTime column.

Below is the query which I created

> ALTER TABLE public.transaction
> ADD COLUMN "transactionDate" timestamp without time zone GENERATED ALWAYS AS (timestamp("dateTime")::date) STORED;

and I'm getting below error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""dateTime""
> LINE 2: ... without time zone GENERATED ALWAYS AS (timestamp("dateTime"...
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 121

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using `timestamp()` for?

For generated column, it should be like -

```
ALTER TABLE transaction ADD COLUMN "transactionDate" timestamp without time zone GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("dateTime"::date) STORED;
```

OR

```
ALTER TABLE transaction ADD COLUMN "transactionDate" timestamp without time zone GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("dateTime"::timestamp) STORED;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/RqY1LGvl).

Comment: Will this give me a output in MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM format?

Answer (score 0):

The column `dateTime` is already a timestamp so you **do not** need to create a timestamp from it. So just: ( see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/5hYqMBh1))

```
alter table transaction  
      add column "transactionDate" date
         generated always as ("dateTime"::date) stored;
```

Comment: I run this query in pgadmin and it's giving error

`ERROR:  unterminated quoted identifier at or near ""dateTime::date) STORED;"
LINE 3: GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("dateTime::date) STORED;
                             ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 87`

Comment: I did change 

`ALTER TABLE public.transaction
ADD COLUMN "transactionDate" DATE
GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("dateTime"::date) STORED;` 

and it's giving `ERROR:  generation expression is not immutable
SQL state: 42P17`

Comment: There is a missing double quote after dateTime. Line should read `generated always as ("dateTime"::date) stored;` Think this comes from the fact that I never use double quoted column names unless they are already there.

Comment: @Belayer What kept you from fixing it?